# .click() working with document.getElementById, but not with jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

This works:

```
$(function() {
    document.getElementById('click').click();
});
```

This doesn't:

```
$(function() {
    $('#click').click();
});
```

Why?

EDIT: (for completeness sake; an answer has been reached):

```
$(function() {
    $('#click').trigger('click')
});
```

also fails

Comment: Try `.trigger('click')`

Comment: try ` $('#click')[0].click();`

Comment: @gurvinder372 - this works, why? What is the [0] referencing and why is it needed?

Comment: Are you sure it's not working? The jQuery API docs, say that using `click()` without any parameters will trigger the click event on the targeted element.

Comment: @evolutionxbox - .trigger('click') also fails.

Comment: `[0]` is dereferencing, getting the first element from the jQuery collection for you to trigger a click on...

Comment: Then your element does not exist, or jQuery isn't referenced properly.

Comment: @evolutionxbox - it does, as document.getElementById and using [0] work. Jquery is working elsewhere.

Comment: What is `#click`? Is it something which has a click event listener attached to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why?

Because jquery [click](https://api.jquery.com/click/) method accepts a handler which will be called on click.

However, DOM [click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) method simulates the click method itself.

You need to

```
$('#click')[0].click();
```

or trigger it

```
$('#click').trigger('click')
$('#click').click();
```

Last two will work only if there is a event-handler assigned. That is, it won't fire simple `anchor` click but `onclick` event will be invoked.

Here is the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/okzg88aL/)

**DEMO**

```js
function f1()
{
   document.getElementById("link1").click();
   document.getElementById("link2").click();
}

function f2()
{
   $("#link1").click();
   $("#link2").click();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:alert(1)" id="link1">Link 1 </a>
<a onclick="alert(2)" id="link2">Link 2 </a>

<button onclick="f1();">DOM click</button>

<button onclick="f2();">Jquery Click</button>
```

Comment: $('#click').trigger('click') also fails

Comment: This is not entirely true. "`.click()` - Bind an event handler to the "click" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element." - It says the using the function without an arguement will trigger the event.

Comment: @evolutionxbox DOM method simulates click while jquery method invokes handler - big difference.

Comment: The jQuery docs say that `.click` will trigger the event, not invoke the handler.

Comment: @evolutionxbox check the test fiddle

Comment: riiiiiiggght, that makes total sense

Answer (score 2):

A better question would be, **why do you think it should work?**

Two completely different pieces of code, why would they work the same?

Specifically, in the first case, you have an HTML element of some kind, and you are calling its native `.click()` method, which triggers a click on it (usually for links or buttons)

On the other hand, the second one gets a jQuery collection, containing a single element (or no element if it doesn't exist). For a jQuery collection, calling `.click()` attaches an event handler to the `click` event for all elements in the collection.

So...

On the one hand, you call a function that triggers a click.
On the other, you call a function that binds an event handler to the `click` event on all elements in the collection.

Why do you think that should work??